# Are there any guarded parking lots anywhere in or near Berlin, Germany?

Tags: germany, automobiles, security, berlin

Are there any guarded parking lots in or around the city of Berlin in Germany?

By guarded parking I do NOT mean "guarded" by an automated gate or camera - that is a joke. I mean a real guarded parking lot with a real human guard on the spot 24h/day, AND the parking takes full liability for the vehicles against theft of and from the vehicles.

There are some parking lots near airports that market themselves as guarded, but when you read the terms and conditions, they write they are only liable for potential theft and damage by their own employees, but are not liable for anything done by a third party, which amused me how can someone offer such useless fake-guarded parking.

There are plenty of really guarded parking lots with human guards 24h/day on the spot in Poland, in every polish city, and I am surprised by a complete absence of such of such parking lots in Germany. Maybe there are hidden somewhere, because I can hardly believe there are none. And don't tell me they are not needed, because car thefts in Germany are on higher level then in Poland: 1.9 per 1000 vehicles per year in Germany, while only 0.9 per 1000 vehicles per year in Poland (data for years 2008-2010).

Where is the closest guarded parking to Berlin?

Comment: Keep in mind that labor costs are higher in Germany, so I'd expect there to be fewer guarded parking lots. Park in Słubice? But try higher-end hotels, if you can afford them.

Comment: @Gilles the thing is I don't need a hotel, I just want to leave my car in Berlin for some time and travel away from the city by other means. Low-end labor is just about 3 to 4 times more expensive then in Poland, so I expect the parking to cost 3 to 4 times more, but its not a reason for them to not exist at all.

Comment: you cannot just look at the low-end labor price and assume that u can multiply services prices by the same factor. If people earn more money, also the prices rises. For rent, electricity, assurance,… and suddenly a price for a service is 10 times more expensive.

Comment: @Gilles: there is no minimum wage in germany; but yeah, of course they try to keep it as cheap as possible and use cameras and a single guy watching ~40 monitors :|

Comment: I have never heard of a guarded parking that takes responsibility for theft in my life (I have lived in Spain, France, UK, and Germany).

Comment: One more thing to consider if you decide to park your car for an extended time in public space in Berlin is that you need to move it once in a while. Parking your car in public for longer than 2 weeks is a parking violation.

Comment: Actually, Berlin [seems to have 3,5/1000](http://www.gdv.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Tabelle_Autodiebstahl_2015_Gro%C3%9Fst%C3%A4dte_WEB.jpg) but that still doesn't tell us how many if any were stolen from guarded car parks.

Comment: No parking will ever accept liability for theft or damage. That's just bad business.

Comment: Of course, the guards must have machine guns, otherwise it's a joke?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Autohotel](http://www.autohotel.org/). They have parking spaces near the Tegel and Schönefeld airports.

An alternative would be to subscribe an insurance against theft or a comprehensive insurance for the duration of your absence, and leave the car in an unguarded parking. I would consider this option and calculate the price for it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any guarded parking lots according to your definition in Germany. But I really don't know anybody here in Germany, whose car was ever stolen in a park garage.

Of course car theft exists in Germany, but it doesn't seem to be such a big issue that anybody would provide guarded parking lots. And every car in Germany is insured against car theft.

Comment: "every car in Germany is insured against car theft" - obviously not! My car is not. Insurance doesn't solve the problem. First of all its handing out money to thieves - I'd gladly pay the money to honest hard working people running parking lots and not to risk-pool which basically is a handout to criminals. Secondly the car is too old to be insured, and even if a company agrees to insure it, its book value is MUCH less then its value to me, and the amount of work I put into customization. Third, the contents of the car can be more valuable then the vehicle itself, and insurance doesn't cover.

Comment: I guess owners of the car garages made some cost-benefit analysis and obviously human guards except the ones monitoring the video system don't bring a benefit regarding to car theft.

Comment: "every car in Germany is insured against car theft" - please edit this out. This is blatantly false, as far as I can tell.